# How to Limit URL: "#{id} #{name}".parameterize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, model, limit

When a user creates a `valuation` (aka value) the `:name` of that valuation becomes part of the url because of this method:

**valuation.rb**

```
def to_param
  "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
end
```

For example if the user creates a value:

> Once more into the fray. The last good fight I’ll ever know. Live and
>   die on this day. Live and die on this day.

The url would be http://www.personalcontrolcenter.com/valuations/33-once-more-into-the-fray-the-last-good-fight-i-ll-ever-know-live-and-die-on-this-day-live-and-die-on-this-day

That is waaaaaay too long. I'd like to `limit` it to 15 characters. Here were my attempts:

**#1**

```
def to_param
  "#{id} #{name}".limit(15).parameterize # undefined method limit error
end
```

**#2**

```
def to_param
  ["#{id} #{name}".limit(15)].parameterize # undefined method limit error
end
```

**#3**

```
def to_param
  "#{id} #{name}".parameterize.limit(15) # undefined method limit error
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"#{id} #{name}".parameterize.first(15)
```